# Squid Transparent Caching

Tags: cache, squid

I want to know that Is it necessary to have two interfaces for Squid Transparent Caching Sever,

1 for LAN users

2 for Internet Connectivity (In a mapped scenario)?

In case if it Yes,please tell me why, and how the Squid Box will route the LAN requests coming from the LAN users to the interface where Internet is  connected.

We are using a UTM , so the way we like to setup this Squid is like this:

```
  LAN user : 192.168.2.x/24
```

LAN gateway : 192.168.2.1

```
 Squid proxy : 192.168.3.2
```

Squid gateway : 192.168.3.1

Internet interface: WAN0 (whatever may be the ip address)

Consider squid proxy port as 3128(default port)

LAN users port 80 request is mapped (DNAT) to 192.168.3.2:3128

=>(WEB address)x.x.x.x:80--->192.168.3.2:3128

If it is a Cache Miss Squid should get it from Internet(SNAT):

192.168.3.2:xxxx--->WAN0

OS:Ubuntu 14.04  64-bit

Also tell me the best practice.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, Squid proxy does not need multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

No the proxy does not require mutiple interfaces nor NIC's.

However, multiple NIC can be useful to maximize bandwidth availability. An interception proxy machine manages both client and erver connections. About twice as much bandwidth as any other type of service would handle. Using a single NIC means only half the NIC bandwidth is available for clients to contact the proxy.